# Strange folders containing datastore files in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

As I'm cleaning up my Windows 10 installation for a complete reinstall, **I stumbled upon several folders with names like *!!4072*, *~~45AF*, *!!47CD*, *!!47A3*, *~~46CA***, &c. 

The ~~-folders only were found in folders already containing a !!-folder: it seems that once there is a folder with the !!-prefix, another one with a ~~-prefix is generated.

They are located in *..\User\Local Settings\*, *..\User\Application Data\*, *..\User\Appdata\Local\*, *..\User\Appdata\Roaming\*, *..\User\Desktop\*, and *c:\Windows\*.

but not, for example, in *..\User\Documents\*, *..\User\Favourites\*, *..\User\Roaming\*.

**Every single one of these contains four files, all named *datastore*, with four distinct extensions: .csv, .jpg, .pdf, and .txt.**

- Both the .csv and .txt files contain five rows of

  > "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
  >   nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
  >   sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
  >   rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem
  >   ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
  >   sadipscing elitr,  sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
  >   dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam
  >   et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
  >   takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
  >   amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,  sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
  >   invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
  >   At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita
  >   kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
  >   amet."

  The .txt file does not have the quotation marks.
- The .jpg is an image of 500 x 500 pixels of the extension letters against a warm red background:

  [image: datastore.jpg]
- The .pdf contains the following text:

  [image]

The only two pages I was able to find (searching for ' "datastore.csv" "datastore.pdf" ') that seem to address this phenomenon, are [a Microsoft forums thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/f90b1ef6-c50f-4a0a-b594-176aef170dad/4619-and-4a57-what-are-they?forum=sapi), and [a seemingly auto-generated list of problems from a Microsoft Community thread](http://fresh3653.rssing.com/chan-58603767/all_p45937.html).

**Does anyone have any idea what generated these?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same problem. Turns out a program called RansomStopper by CyberSight is causing these strange named folders.

Uninstalling fixes the issue.

Comment: I think I indeed had that installed. Thank you!